# Turn regular function into generator

Tags: python

What is the pythonic way to convert/modify regular function to make a single value generator?

Possible usage: pass a function where generator is expected.

I am thinking to do something like this:

```
# some function
def foo():
    return Bar()

def gen_foo()
    yield foo()
```

Comment: Do you mean a generator of functions?

Comment: What's wrong with your solution? Seems fine to me...

Comment: You question is unclear. Please try to explain what you mean better and show an example that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you said pass a function into a place where a generator is expected, I assume you are talking about it expects a sequence that can be iterated over (i.e. an iterator) using either a for loop or `next()`. In this case, the easiest way is actually not making a wrapper function around it but just to pass a sequence containing that function (assuming that your function does not return a sequence). Let's say you have

```py
def foo():
    return 1
```

Then the easiest way to pass it to where a sequence is expected is, of course, a tuple or a list. Note this only works if the function expecting it is using a for loop internally.

```py
(foo(), )
# or
[foo()]
```

But then, the function expecting the sequence may be iterating everything manually using `next()`, in which case you can just pass in

```py
iter([foo()])
```

to get an iterator that produces that function and nothing else. This approach is basically the same as your `gen_foo()` and produces the same result. However, you might also want an iterator to return an infinite copy of your function, in which case you can use

```py
import itertools
itertools.repeat(foo())
```

which will create an infinite amount of (the return value of) `foo`.

Comment: This is very pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```py
def make_generator(function):
    yield function()
```